# How to get Excel out of Select Cell mode

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2003

Looking for a tip on Microsoft Excel (2003):

If you click on a cell containing a formula, click into the formula, and click away, Excel will enter the cell or range you next select into the formula at the cursor. This is fine and dandy a lot of times, but right now I am working with a spreadsheet that has a lot of really long formulas. If I click into a cell and it goes into the state where it wants to enter a reference to the next cell I click into the formula, I can't always get out of it, and if I click on something, I don't always even know what the change was (these are *really* long formulas).

So my question is, is there a keystroke I can press or some other action to immediately get out of "input the next thing you click" mode and be sure there are no side effects? Ctrl-Z doesn't do it.

Comment: As a side note, try using "Named ranges" and "constants" it helps make formulas more readable, and will reduce their length too!

Comment: If only the original programmer of this spreadsheet had had this advice. Though to be fair it's really pushing Excel to its limits. I am converting it to a program.

Comment: Matt's advice is good, and you can still replace ranges with defined names going forward

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit Esc or Enter I believe.

Comment: Esc will cancel what you've typed, and Enter will save it.

Comment: The inverse to this is if you have a cell selected and want to start typing in it, press F2 to begin editing it.

Comment: Ooh, the F2 thing is great, too.

Answer (score 3):

Hit the escape key.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

... at least, that’s the answer as far as my understanding of your question goes:

> … to immediately get out of “input the next thing you click” mode and be sure there are no side effects?

, which is rather vague.

Comment: But this will save any changes you might have made, which seems to be counter to the "no side effects" requirement.

Comment: Perhaps. The question is vague; however, generally, a side effect is an effect secondary to a main effect. The requirement was to avoid side effects. Presumably, one would want to save changes made; otherwise, why would the changes have been made, unless erroneously? Esc; Enter; or Ctrl + Enter; or yet still Tab; or even Shift + Enter all could work, depending on the task.